# Shell script to restart django runserver inside the screen

Tags: django, bash, shell, gnu-screen

how to restart django runserver using a shell script? i ran the django server inside a screen.

this is my shell script restartpython.sh:

```
killall -9 python
screen -r
sleep 5
exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
ctrl+a d          # how to make this into shell script??
```

when i execute this script, i enter the screen and the python server is killed. but the script didn't run this line:

```
exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It shows this error:

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Also, how to run ctrl+a d in shell script (to exit from the screen)?. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a hacked together pseudo-production configuration. [`runserver` isn't meant to be used in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#runserver). What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Chris i'm trying to make a script to restart the django runserver. because, the django runserver is stuck sometimes. i'm still on development phase now. i will use other method on production.

Comment: Normally I just run `python manage.py` and leave it running in an open terminal window. Is there any particular reason you're complicating matters by adding `screen` and a custom shell script into the mix? (Note that `killall -9 python` is almost certainly not something that should be in there. And you probably don't need `exec` either…)

Comment: @Chris i use screen because i want to run django in the background and i can exit the ssh and leave it running.

Comment: You're using a remote server for development? In that case I'd consider writing an init script for whatever OS you have on the server. It may be easier to just run your development server on your local dev box, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of runserver, use [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) and [`kill -HUP`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-reload-my-application-in-gunicorn) to reload your server.

Comment: That means giving up the development server's auto-reloading functionality…

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes